# MacBook Air M1 - PRAW installation

Tags: python, web-scraping, reddit, praw

I have a MacBook Air M1 2020 with macOS Big Sur and I'm trying to work on a Reddit scraping project.
To do so, I need to import PRAW to use it in my Python code.
After reading a few posts here, I saw that using `pip3 install praw` was preferable for this system, which seemed to work for me.

However, when I run my code in Visual Studio Code this message appears right away:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'praw'
```

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how do you run python code with your PRAW import? Your python script execution environment (the one selected on visual studio code) may not be the same as the base environment of your MacBook, where you executed your pip3 command.

I suggest you to read the [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments) of visual studio code for python to understand how to visualize your environment in VS code.

In your terminal you can run the following command to check that the path of python3 is the same as the one of your visual studio code environment.

```
$ whereis python3
```

Comment: Hi,
It works now, thank you so much!
I learned something today!